# iterate through 2 big dataframes with different length (if, else)

Tags: r

I worked for a while and still not finding an efficient way to handle this matter.

I have two data frames and both are very huge.

df1 looks like (one ID could have multiple prices):

```
ID       Price

1          20
1           9
2          12
3          587
3           59
3           7
4           78
5           12
6          290
6          191
...
1000000    485
```

df2 looks like(one ID only have one location):

```
ID       Location     
1           USA
2           CAN
3           TWN
4           USA
5           CAN
6           AUS
...
100000      JAP
```

I want to create a new data frame looks like (create Location to df1 based on ID):

```
ID       Price     Location

1          20        USA
1           9        USA
2          12        CAN
3          587       TWN
3           59       TWN
3           7        TWN
4           78       USA
5           12       CAN
6          290       AUS
6          191       AUS
...
1000000    485       JAP
```

I tried "merge" but R gave me `negative length vectors are not allowed`.  Both lists are huge, one over 2M rows and one over 0.6M rows.

I also tried lapply inside a loop but failed.  I cannot figure out how to handle this matter except using two loops (and two nested loops will take a long time).

Comment: For large data perhaps try the data.table options at the duplicate question. A merge/join will be more efficient than a double loop. Make sure IDs are unique in `df2`.

Comment: @MrFlick, IDs are unique in df2 and I tried the method provided below. Unfortunately, I got an error message. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a `join` with `data.table` for efficiently creating the column 'Location'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, Location := Location, on = .(ID)]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but get an error message as below: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: @mimibao1009 Okay, then you may need more memory machine.

Comment: It finally worked after I rename the columns from Location to location.... @@"  Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I don't understand how the column name affects but I am glad it finally works. Also, I think you may right about the memory part because R ran for a while.

Comment: Again, thank you so much.  :-D

Comment: just did.  Thank you again.